How to Make Timeline Animation Repeat Forever in Reality Composer Pro?
Hi I have set up an animation using timeline in Reality Composer Pro like below

This gets triggered from a notification posts from the code. Once this time line is triggered, I want to repeat the 2 animations in the timeline until user takes the next action. How can I make these repeat forever?

Repeat Forever the Timeline Actions in RCP 2.0
It seems strange that Reality Composer Pro 2.0 does not yet reach the functionality that was in the deprecated Reality Composer 1.5. But nevertheless, you can easily do what you need to. Place animation actions on the timeline and set up them the way you want. In my example, the total duration on the timeline is 2 sec.

After that add OnAddedToScene behavior with Timeline action and then export a model with animation as .usdz file. Reimport a new model with animation into RCP 2.0 and place it in the scene. Create new empty timeline, and apply Animation action to it.

Do not delete the old timeline as the animated model references it.
Use the following settings for Animation layer:

Click on the Play button to make sure that the animation loops endlessly.

